# looping through an array backwards from current position

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to java and android so be patient with me. I have an xml layout containing two buttons. One containing text of "previous" and the other "next". I also have a class containing array of strings which loops in an ascending order in a `textView` when a "next" button is clicked.

What i want is that i want the array to loop backwards from its current position when the "previous" button is clicked. Any ideas?

**Question Class**

```
// This file contains questions from QuestionBank
class Question{
    // array of questions
    private String mQuestions [] = {
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
    // method returns number of questions
    int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    // method returns question from array textQuestions[] based on array index
    String getQuestion(int a) {
        return mQuestions[a];
    }
}
```

**Main Activity.java**

```
     public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {
                private QuestionLibraryBeginner mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibraryBeginner();
                private int mQuestionNumber = 1; // current question number
            //initialising navigation buttons
                private Button mPrevious;
                private Button mNext;
            private TextView mQuestionText;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beginner_review);
                    mPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
                    mNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
  mQuestionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
                    // receive the current question number from last activity by Intent


        Intent intent = getIntent();
             currentQuestionNumber = intent.getIntExtra("quizNumber", 0); // receiving the number of questions the user has attempted from previous activity
                    mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
    // checking against total number of questions the user has attempted instead of total number of questions from Question Class
    if (mQuestionNumber < currentQuestionNumber) {
             updateQuestion();
                        }
                    });
                    mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
            // i want it to loop backwards from here
                        }
                    });

            // logic to update question from array
                private void updateQuestion() {
                    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
                        mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a greater than condition and decrement operator --

Comment: yeah. but i also need the strings in my array to loop backwards in my  textView

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest to do this:**

1) Rename `updateQuestion` method to `nextQuestion`

2) Create a method to decrease the mQuestionNumber like this:

```
private void prevQuestion(){
    if(mQuestionNumber > 0){
    mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
    mQuestionNumber--;}
}
```

Comment: @Bennykeys Since "updateQuestion" from the original Code is incrementing mQuestionNumber after displaying an item, I decided to do the same since I wasn't sure if that's the intended way(Clicking the button the first time Shows the old value, clicking it the next time will Show the decremented value). For me it would be more useful to increment/decrement the int before updating the TextView.

Comment: nothing happens when i click "mNext Button" after placing logic in mPrevious button. Why is that?

Comment: @Bennykeys because you try to do many things in one place, decouple them, check my clean solution and read something about Oop principles

Comment: @BennyKeys I can't tell why it's not working as long as I don't see what exactly you have done. But I think that fxrbfg is right. Decoupling is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @BennyKeys i just saw that you declared the variable "private TextView mQuestionText;" but i cannot find where you assigned it to an actual TextView.

Comment: oops. it was something i committed while presenting my code here.

Comment: however, according to my updated code, i am now checking against number of questions the user attempted instead of length of array. do you have a way round that?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the following methodes:

would remove mQuestionNummer++; from update question.

You can increment mQuestions directly in the onClickMethode of NextButton.

So you can implement your solution simply by decrement mQuestion-- in onClick of previous Button.

Code would look like this:

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {
    private QuestionLibraryBeginner mQuestionLibrary = new 
    QuestionLibraryBeginner();
    private int mQuestionNumber = 1; // current question number
    //initialising navigation buttons
    private Button mPrevious;
    private Button mNext;
    private TextView mQuestionText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beginner_review);
        mPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        mNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        // receive the current question number from last activity by Intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
                mQuestionNumber++;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // i want it to loop backwards from here
                            if(mQuestionNumber > 0){
                                mQuestionNumber--;
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            else
                                {}//don't do anything to prevent IndexOutOfBounds
            }
    });

    // logic to update question from array
    private void updateQuestion() {
        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for this. however, according to my updated code, i am now checking against number of questions the user attempted instead of length of array. And your logic doesn't work on that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution accounting for bounds

```
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        showNextQuestion();
    }
});
mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        showPreviousQuestion();
    }
});

private void showNextQuestion() {
    showQuestion(1);
}

private void showPreviousQuestion() {
    showQuestion(-1);
}

private void showQuestion(int increment) {
    int newQuestionNumber = mQuestionNumber + increment;
    if (newQuestionNumber >= 0 && newQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionNumber = newQuestionNumber;
        mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by just adding a `flag` to mention the move,

```
mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateQuestion(true); 
        });
mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateQuestion(false);
            }
        });
```

**And the method would look like:**

```
private void updateQuestion(boolean forward) {
        if(forward && mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength())
            mQuestionNumber++
        else if (mQuestionNumber>1)
            mQuestionNumber--;
        mQuestionText.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
}
```

Comment: why do i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException with your code when i get to the last item?

Answer (score 0):

You need to don't mess logic of your application with view logic, decouple them. 
Just make class Question able to provide previous and next questions. Also according to oop principles (solid, grasp) fetch information from class and make decision outside is wrong, make class to do it's work. Oop it's about telling classes to do things, not work instead of them.

```
class Questions {
    private int index = 0;

    private String[] mQuestions;

    //better to don't hardcode and provide questions in constructor
    public Question(String[] questions) {
        this.questions = questions;

    }

    //we don't need this method
    int getLength(){
        return mQuestions.length;
    }


    //provide human readable information about current position in question list
    // when you want to provide this information to user introduce label field in activity
    public String currentPosition() {
        int questionPosition = index + 1;
        int questionsLength = mQuestions.length;
        return String.format("current question number is %d from %d" , questionPosition, questionsLength);
    }


    //return next question when available, if next not available returns last question from array
    public String next() {
        int lastIndex = mQuestions.length - 1;
        if(index < lastIndex) {
            index++;
        }
        return mQuestions[index];
    }

    //return current question
    public String current() {
        return mQuestions[index];
    }

    //return previous question when available, if previous not available returns first question from array
    public String previous() {
        int firstIndex = 0;
        if(index > firstIndex) {
            index--;
        }
        return mQuestions[index];

    }

}
```

And how to use it in Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //better to don't hardcode here, but provide this class from
    //constructor of MainActivity just like questions array provide 
    // to constructor in Questions class
    private Questions questions = new Questions(new String[]{"q1","q2"});
    private Button mPrevious;
    private Button mNext;
    private TextView mQuestionText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beginner_review);
        mPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        mNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //when create Activity populate question field with first question
        mQuestionText.setText(questions.current());

        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQuestionText.setText(questions.next());
            }
        });


        mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQuestionText.setText(questions.previous());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

p.s. you may improve this code further in way to introduce *Observer* pattern, Activity is a view, Questions is model.

Comment: thank you for your advice. i would try that. However, i have an important question.

Comment: what if i am checking against the total number of questions the user has attempted rather than the length of array from my QuestionClass.

Comment: for example if you review my updated code above, you would see that i passed the number of questions the user has attempted from the previous activity which means the questions would be limited to the total number of questions attempted.

Comment: So if am to decouple my logic like you advised, how would that affect your logic since i cant get Intent from model class

Comment: @Bennykeys you need to keep state not in Activity, Intent, etc. you need to keep it in Questions class and pass it through activities with help of bundles